# vue function does not run after mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, hook, loaded

A memory-game I am creating, I would like to start immediately after the page is loaded.

To start I need to createDeck() and showCards()

I tried several things  in the export default {} like:

```
   created(){
     this.createDeck(),
     this.createShowCards()
   },
```

and

```
    mounted() {
      this.fetchCards(),    // also need to fetch the cards, this works ok...
      this.createDeck(),
      this.createShowCards()
      console.log('component mounted')
    },
```

I can get the game working when calling the startfunctions with a start button:

```
 <div class="text-center">
   <button  @click="startGame()" v-if="Object.keys(cards).length != 0">Start game</button>
 </div>
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am missing?
How can I get the "button to be clicked automatically"  ?

Comment: Is `fetchCards()` a sync request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wait cards to load:

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.fetchCards()
  this.createDeck()
  this.createShowCards()    
},
```

and maybe you need to make that function async like

```
async fetchCards() { await ...}
```

Comment: @M.Koops hey mate, can you show your `fetchCards` function? Maybe you need to make that function async like `async fetchCards() { await ...}`

Comment: Thanks for the help. fetchcards is an async function.  The solution suggested above does work fine.